# Convert a text file to supply dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples

What is the best solution to my problem? Let's say I want to open a text file like this;

```
[1 (100, 100, name)]
[2 (200, 200, name)]
[3 (300, 300, name)]
```

Using this text file I want to supply it to a Dictionary<int, Tuple<double, double, string>>

What I tried:

```
Dictionary<int, Tuple<double, double, string>> text_to_dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<double, double, string>>();
    
    foreach(var item TextFileToSupplyDictionary())
    {
     text_to_dictionary.add(item)
    }
    
    public Dictionary<int, Tuple<double, double, string>>  TextFileToSupplyDictionary()
            {
                var res = File
                    .ReadLines("textFile")
                    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                    .GroupBy(item => Convert.ToInt32(item[0]))
                    .ToDictionary(groupValues => groupValues.Key, groupValues => groupValues.ToDictionary(item => Convert.ToDouble(item[1]), item => Convert.ToDouble(item[2])));
    
                return res;
            }
```

I didn't really know where I was going with this...

Also I have this error:
[image]

Comment: Do you have control over the format of the text file? Or is it "this is what you get, deal with it"?

Comment: Your foreach are missing the `in` keyword

Comment: the values in the dictionary need to be tuples and not other dictionaries. this is why you get the error

Comment: nope those are fix values

Comment: You need to create a `Tuple` in `ToDictionary` call. Also, `Split(',')` here will not work because you shouldn't just split it with comma delimiter.

Comment: why would you use group by? do you expect to have multiple entries with the same first integer number? if so then how do you want to handle all the other values ? only 1 key is allowed in the dictionary.

Comment: are the parentheses: `[1` also in the file? your code does not handle this. Any conversion to int or double will fail.

Comment: Usually, I am the last to say "Regex", but ... https://regex101.com/r/IXb5ha/2 ?

Comment: ^^ https://dotnetfiddle.net/hIe4iv

Comment: @Fildor nice one, post it as answer mate :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to either remove or split on the other characters in the string that you don't need, and then select the first item as the key and a tuple created from the other items as the value:

```
var dictionary = File
    .ReadLines("textFile")
    .Select(line => line.Split(new[] {'[', '(', ',', ')', ']'},
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .ToDictionary(x => int.Parse(x[0]),
        x => new Tuple<double, double, string>(
            double.Parse(x[1]), double.Parse(x[2]), x[3].Trim()));
```

Comment: this saves my day! :)

Comment: Glad it helps. Note that it's blindly using `int.Parse` and `double.Parse`, so it will throw an exception if those parts of the file can't be parsed to the appropriate type. It could be made safer by adding validation to each line, but if the contents are well formed it should do the trick as is.

Comment: @Rufus, I have one query, will this work if "name" i.e. in text file contains characters like ( or , or [ etc.?

Comment: Nope, that would break this too. Is that a valid scenario?

Comment: Yes it will break.@redbeef, do you think that "name" will never have data which can contains these characters? If no, I would suggest to use regex solution that I have given. Please let me know If I missed something.

Comment: @Vikas Garg luckily the thing "name" is just a plain string but still its a good idea to put regex in case there was at unusual characters

Answer (score 2):

Usually, I'd be the last one to suggest Regex, but here ...

Disclaimer: Please do excessive testing ( performance / load / memory ... ) if you decide to use Regex!

This is a first approach:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string dummyfile = "[1 (100, 100, name)]\n[2 (200, 200, name)]\n[3 (300, 300, name)]\n";
        
        var regex = new Regex(@"^\[(?<index>\d*)\s+\((?<num1>\d+),\s+(?<num2>\d+),\s+(?<name>.+)\)\]$", RegexOptions.Multiline );
        
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(dummyfile);
        
        Console.WriteLine("Matches: {0}", matches.Count);
        foreach( Match match in matches )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found {0}: {1} | {2} | {3}", match.Groups["index"], match.Groups["num1"], match.Groups["num2"], match.Groups["name"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Which ran on dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jbob0S

An example that's more tailored to your specific situation:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string dummyfile = "[1 (100, 100, name)]\n[2 (200, 200, name)]\n[3 (300, 300, name)]\n";
        var regex = new Regex(@"\[(?<index>\d*)\s+\((?<num1>\d+),\s+(?<num2>\d+),\s+(?<name>.+)\)\]" );
        
        var result = dummyfile.Split('\n', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select( l => DoTheMatch( l, regex )).ToList();
    
        foreach( var item in result )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found {0}: {1} | {2} | {3}", item.Index, item.Num1, item.Num2, item.Name);
        }
    }
    
    public static Data DoTheMatch( string line, Regex regex )
    {
        Match match = regex.Match(line);
        if( match.Success )
        {
            return new Data(){Index = int.Parse(match.Groups["index"].Value), Num1 = int.Parse(match.Groups["num1"].Value), Num2 = int.Parse(match.Groups["num2"].Value), Name= match.Groups["name"].Value};
        }
        throw new Exception( string.Format("Invalid line '{0}'", line) );
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public int Index {get; set;}
    public int Num1 {get; set;}
    public int Num2 {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/z8BLEM

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, below solution will work for you with regex. String.Split will fail if "name" in text file contain "[",",","(" etc characters. Please let me know if I missed something.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"^\[(?<DicIndex>\d*)\s+\((?<FirstNumber>\d+),\s+(?<SecondNumber>\d+),\s+(?<name>.+)\)\]$", RegexOptions.Multiline);

        var res = File
          .ReadLines(@"C:\TEST\Dictionary.txt")
          .Select(item => regex.Matches(item))
          .Select(a => new { key = a[0].Groups[1].Value, value = new Tuple<double, double, string>(Convert.ToDouble(a[0].Groups[2].Value), Convert.ToDouble(a[0].Groups[3].Value), Convert.ToString(a[0].Groups[4].Value)) })
          .ToDictionary(key => key.key, value => value.value);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this code. you forgot to create a `Typle` in your code just use `Dictionary` so you got error

```
var dictionary = File
            .ReadLines("textFile")
            .Select(e => e.Split("[(,)]".ToCharArray() , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            .ToDictionary(key => int.Parse(key[0]), values => new Tuple<double, double, string>(
                Convert.ToDouble(values[1]), Convert.ToDouble(values[2]), values[3]));
```

Comment: you forgot to handle the `[ ]` square brakets. This breaks at runtime. cannot convert